# What is the existence operator in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

In Objective C this is a valid line of code

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.image ? self.image.size : CGSizeZero;
```

Which is checking if self.image is nil or not, and choosing the left or right value. 
In Swift I want to recreate the same line of code. Actually it should be exactly the same except without the semicolon

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.image ? self.image.size : CGSizeZero
```

But this is not valid in my Swift code getting an error, 'UIImage does not conform to protocol LogicValue'

What is the correct Swift code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code works if self.image is an Optional. There is no reason to have it otherwise because self.image literally cannot be nil.

The following code is completely valid:

```
var image : UIImage?
self.scrollView.contentSize = image ? image!.size : CGSizeZero
```

**Note:** you must use the "!" to "unwrap" the optional variable `image` so that you can access its `size`. This is safe because you just tested before hand that it is not nil.

This would also work if image is an implicitly unwrapped optional:

```
var image : UIImage!
self.scrollView.contentSize = image ? image.size : CGSizeZero
```

Comment: I am wondering. Do you have to use self to access instance variables that you define at the top of the file? Usually I always use self to access these but it looks like it will work and compile either way. So when to use self?

Comment: @nearpoint Technically `self` is only required if you have a local variable with the same name as a member variable or you are trying to use a member variable or method in a closure. However, I also prefer to always use `self` as I think it makes the intent more clear. I didn't use it in my example because my code isn't in the context of a class and I just created the image in the line above.

Comment: @hnh :/ I said that exact thing "or you are trying to use a member variable or method in a closure", but I guess more clarification can't hurt :)

Answer (score 0):

You are describing the conditional assignment ternary operator `?:`, which operates as so:

```
(condition) ? (assign this value if the condition evaluates to true) : (assign this value if the condition evaluates to false)
```

therefore, `self.image` needs to be something that evaluates to `true` or `false`, which is the case in Swift for anything that conforms to the `LogicValue` protocol

unlike Obj-C where the mere presence of an object is equivalent to `true`, Swift requires a little more... we are given Optional Values that can be used as conditionals!

so what you described works if `self.image` is an optional value, which it sounds like it is not if you are seeing that error

to round out the answer:

- if self.image is not optional, it can never be nil so you can safely make the assignment without doing the conditional check
- if it is possible at some point that self.image may be nil, then it needs to be one of the optional types, either `UIImage?` or `UIImage!` (implicitly unwrapped optional, see https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)